# Add Scala SDK to ALL modules in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

We have a Gradle multi-project which we successfully import into Intellij using the in-built import-functionality.

In total, we have about ~150 subprojects with one or more modules, with both Scala and Java-code. For Intellij to work properly with Scala, each module with Scala code needs to have a configured Scala SDK.

Is there any way to configure Intellij to use a Scala SDK on the root project, ALL modules in a project, or similar?

Best Regards,
/d

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may do it in `Project Structure` dialog. Find scala-sdk in `Libraries` or `Global Libraries` tab and select `Add to modules` in the context menu:

[image]

Comment: But actually, it should be done automatically on project import. Can you create a ticket with an example of gradle build definition which reproduces this problem?
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL#newissue