# Scala build error on Java 11 using intellijidea

Tags: java, scala, gradle, java-11

When I build my project from IntellijIdea I get the following errors

```
Error:scalac: 'jvm-11' is not a valid choice for '-target'
Error:scalac: bad option: '-target:jvm-11'
```

I am using gradle to build my project. My project is using java 11 and scala 2.12.8.

Can someone help me resolve this error?

Comment: What is your build configuration? Their [official documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html) also reads *As of Scala 2.12.8 and 2.11.12, JDK 11 support is incomplete.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195952/errorscalac-jvm-1-9-is-not-a-valid-choice-for-target

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206635725-Scala-Gradle-and-Java-1-8-problem

Answer (score 4):

Scala 2.12 doesn't support JVM 11 as a target. You need to add this to your gradle build file:

```
tasks.withType<ScalaCompile> {
    targetCompatibility = "1.8"
}
```

As for Scala 2.13, the fix for this issue is:

```
tasks.withType<ScalaCompile>() {
    targetCompatibility = ""
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = listOf("-target:11")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I simply had Scala misconfigured after Idea update.

Scala 12 can in fact be compatible with Java 11. It's better to check compatibility [table](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html).

I had to remove my previous Scala library from `Project Structure` and re-added it as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180339/4470135) answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in IntelliJ (or IntelliJ's Scala plugin):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-18813

I have posted there a workaround, which was inspired by IvanoBulo's answer above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).